# Junit Test return status code 200, expected 400

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I integrated validation with RestControllerAdvice in RestController.

When I request invalid parameter to this controller using postman, it returns reponse code 400.

But in junit test code, it returns 400.

If you let me know what should I do, I'll appreciate.

Here are my codes.

My junit version is 5.8.2

#### Controller

```java
package com.example.applyhome.api.home.controller;

import com.example.applyhome.api.common.domain.ApiResponse;
import com.example.applyhome.api.common.service.ApiService;
import com.example.applyhome.api.home.service.HomeService;
import com.example.applyhome.module.annotation.Api;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Validated
@Api
public class HomeController {
  private final HomeService homeService;
  private final ApiService apiService;

  @GetMapping("/homes/{month}")
  public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getHome(
          @PathVariable("month")
          @Size(min = 6, max = 6)
          @NotNull
          @Pattern(regexp = "^\\d{4}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$")
          String month) {

    return apiService.okResponse(homeService.getHomeList(month));
  }
}
```

#### RestControllerAdvice

```java
package com.example.applyhome.api.common.advice;

import com.example.applyhome.api.common.domain.ApiResponse;
import com.example.applyhome.api.common.service.ApiService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestControllerAdvice;

import javax.validation.ValidationException;

@RestControllerAdvice
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ExceptionControllerAdvice {
  private final ApiService apiService;

  @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
  public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> validationExceptionHandler(ValidationException ve) {
    log.error(ve.getMessage());
    return apiService.badRequest(ve.getMessage().split(","));
  }

}
```

#### ControllerTest

```java
package com.example.applyhome.api.home.controller;

import com.example.applyhome.api.common.advice.ExceptionControllerAdvice;
import com.example.applyhome.api.common.service.ApiService;
import com.example.applyhome.api.home.service.HomeService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.*;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = HomeController.class)
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class HomeControllerTest {
  private MockMvc mockMvc;
  @MockBean
  private HomeService homeService;
  @MockBean
  private ApiService apiService;

  @BeforeEach
  public void setUp() {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new HomeController(homeService, apiService))
            .setValidator(mock(Validator.class))
            .setControllerAdvice(new ExceptionControllerAdvice(apiService))
            .build();
  }

  @Test
  @Order(1)
  void pathVariableTest1() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/" + todayMonth().substring(0, 1))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }
  @Test
  @Order(2)
  void pathVariableTest2() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/" + todayMonth().substring(0, 2))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }
  @Test
  @Order(3)
  void pathVariableTest3() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/" + todayMonth().substring(0, 3))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }
  @Test
  @Order(4)
  void pathVariableTest4() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/" + todayMonth().substring(0, 4))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }

  @Test
  @Order(5)
  void pathVariableTest5() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/2022" + todayMonth().substring(0, 5))
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }

  @Test
  @Order(6)
  void pathVariableTest6() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/" + todayMonth())
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }
  @Test
  @Order(7)
  void pathVariableTest7() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/" + todayMonth() + "0")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }

  @Test
  @Order(8)
  void pathVariableTest8() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/" + todayMonth() + "01")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }

  @Test
  @Order(9)
  void regexpTest1() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/202213")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }

  @Test
  @Order(10)
  void regexpTest2() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/homes/abc")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isBadRequest())
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
  }
  private String todayMonth() {
    return LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMM"));
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: The junit version doesn't matter, what does matter is which Spring BOot version you are using. DItch `@RunWith` that is for JUnit4 (and you state you are using JUnit5).  DItch your `@BeforeEach` method and instead add `@Autowired` to the `MockMvc` field (that is the whole point of `@WebMvcTest` and you are basically throwing all of that out of the window while still incurring the startup cost, so all the pain without the benefits).